# How to get sum of list element by iterating and poping out of the elements

Tags: python, list

I have a list `m = [1,2,3,4]`  need to iterate over the elements by poping out of element one at a time. First time first element will pop out then second, third and fourth

```
n = []
i = 0
m.pop(i);i += 1;  i < len(m)
# [2+3+4, 1+3+4, 1+2+4, 1+2+3]
n =[9,8,7,6]
```

Comment: Why do you need to bother to pop out elements when you could, in turn, subtract each item from the sum?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I'd do this is to iterate over a `range` up to as many elements as there are in the list, copy the list `m` and `pop` the element at the given index, and append the `sum` on each iteration:

```
n = []
for i in range(len(m)):
    temp = m[:]
    temp.pop(i)
    n.append(sum(temp))
```

---

```
print(n)
#[9, 8, 7, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is the sum of combinations of size `3`, for which you can use `itertools.combinations`:

```
from itertools import combinations

m = [1, 2, 3, 4]
s = 3

n = list(map(sum, combinations(m, s)))

print(n)
```

Output:

```
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

If you want the output reversed, just use:

```
n = list(map(sum, combinations(m, s)))[::-1]
```

Output:

```
[9, 8, 7, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just subtract each element from the pre-calculated sum of all elements:

```
m = [1,2,3,4]

sum_of_all_elements = sum(m)

n = [sum_of_all_elements - item for item in m]

print(n)
```

Output:

```
[9, 8, 7, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sum = 0
while m:
    sum += m.pop()
```

Might worth mentioning that due to the fact that in python `lists` are mutable, you'll end up with an empty `m` after this operation.

L.E.: Nevermind; Apparently you were clearly looking for something else, but your question text clearly needs adjusted. There are a bunch of good answers above.